# Let Angular6 compiler fail on forgetting square bracket?

Tags: angular

We're using Angular 6.1 for a large project.
Recently someone committed in this bad code in a template (during a merge), which we overlooked during code review:

```
[input="foo"
```

This should ofcourse have been this:

```
[input]="foo"
```

Strangely the Angular compiler does not complain about this, not in production (AOT) mode which compiles the template.

Is there a way let the compilation fail on errors like this?
Maybe a linter rule or a compiler option I've missed.

I checked the angular compiler documentation and tslint options and rules but couldn't find anything related to this.

Comment: Have you looked at how you are building the project? might not error in a dev build, have you tried a production build?

Comment: Like I said, production (AOT) mode does not complain or error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be hitting a bug in Angular, see here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/20287

which is still in progress here:
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19792

Comment: Yes, it seems to be that Angular CLI compiler bug. It has been open for nearly a year now! One of the killer features of a production build (compile time template checks) is broken for nearly a year :(

Comment: Yeah, I found it a while ago and it is really annoying. This has failed a lot of things for me too

Answer (score 1):

It should show the compile error in fact. Anyhow you can look into **[`Angular language service`](https://angular.io/guide/language-service#angular-language-service)** Service is a way to get completions, errors, hints, and navigation inside your Angular templates

Comment: I have included the language service, and my IDE reports the error alright. Unfortunately that does not help me on our CI/CD server which does the compilation in production mode.

Answer (score 0):

fullTemplateTypeCheck in the angular compiler is buggy and does not pick up errors.

The issue is open for nearly a year, but no progress so far.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19792